# Obtaining only Value component of a Maybe in Haskell

Tags: haskell

have a function that is returning:

`>>> ["Just (Number 8000.0)","Just (Number 93.0)","Just (String \"test\")"]`

What is the best way to get just the values?

`>>> ["8000.0", "93.0", "test"]`

The code is trying to parse JSON, using `prism`s from Aeson.

**Code**

```
jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "test.json"

getJSON :: IO BS.ByteString
getJSON = BS.readFile jsonFile

main :: IO ()
main = do
     input <- getJSON
     print $ f input

f :: BS.ByteString -> [String]
f x = [ show $ (x ^? key "a" . nth 0 . key "b")
        , show $ x ^? key "a" . nth 0 . key "c"
        , show $ x ^? key "a" . nth 0 . key "d" 
        ]
```

Comment: What is the type of the values under `Maybe`? `Number`, `String`, etc.?

Comment: It looks like you have a list of strings, not of `Maybe`. Perhaps the function you have called mapped `show` over your data?

Comment: Could you post the code for the function that produces the output at the top of your question?

Comment: @Koterpiller Aeson returns the data type when I use `prism` to obtain a particular value. so Number is an Int and String is a String

Comment: @matthias remove all the `show` calls and apply `catMaybe` to the result of `f`.

Comment: @Koterpillar the values returned from the JSON are not homogeneous. I have the shows in there to get a list of strings.

Comment: You can apply `show` later, after you extract values from `Maybe`s.

Comment: I get  `[ Number 8000.0,  Number 93.0, String "test"]`. So the "Just" has been removed but I still have the data type names in there. Also, won't  using `catMaybes` remove instances of `nothing` ???? I still would like to keep  them in there.

Comment: It seems like you somehow want to keep the Nothing values... Replace `show $ ...` with `maybe "Nothing" show $ ...` ? This still prints the string `"Nothing"` for any such values in the list, but prints the `Just` values without the `"Just"`.

Comment: @matthias updated my answer to convert everything to strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[catMaybes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) from `Data.Maybe` will only leave `Just` values in the list, discarding any `Nothing`s.

(Hint: you can use Hoogle search for [[Maybe a] -> [a]](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BMaybe%20a%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D)).

Updated: if you want to replace `Nothing` with something else, use [fromMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) with your default value, i.e.

`map (fromMaybe "Nothing") (f x)`

It also looks like you have strings instead of `Maybe` inside the list; you'll have to remove `show` call from each element.

Updated again: let's convert everything to strings!

```
map (fromMaybe "nothing" . fmap show)
```

The outer `map` applies the transformation to each element. `fmap show` converts the values inside `Just` to strings and leaves `Nothing` alone (note the number `1` converted to a string `"1"`:

```
> map (fmap show) [Just 1, Nothing]
[Just "1",Nothing]
```

Then `fromMaybe "nothing"` unpacks `Just` values and replaces `Nothing` with a string of your choice.

```
> map (fromMaybe "nothing" . fmap show) [Just 1, Nothing]
["1","nothing"]
```

I suggest you pay closer attention to types while using Haskell, converting everything to strings removes the benefits of using a well-typed language.

Comment: I am not trying to discard the `Nothings`, I am trying to remove the string "Just" and "Number" or "String" from the output when printed.

Comment: Your probably ought to expand your example to demonstrate the behavior you want when the list contains a `Nothing`, then.

Comment: @ChrisMartin. Having "Nothing" in the list is fine for my purposes.

Comment: @matthias You just have to remove `show` and you won't have any `"Just"` and such. Just do `map show . catMaybes $ f x`.

Comment: @koterpiller thank you for this. I have learned a lot from your posts.